# Spring Boot 1.4 VelocityEngineUtils deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, velocity

i just updated to spring boot 1.4 and noticed that VelocityEngineUtils is deprecated. I am using Velocity Templates to send emails same as in  [spring framework example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mail-templates)

What are the alternative for sending emails templates other than Velocity template

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineUtils.html It says `Deprecated. 
as of Spring 4.3, in favor of FreeMarker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html) is a pretty powerful replacement.

Thymeleaf will do text or html email (see the link above), is already a [recommended templating framework for general HTML use](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines), and Velocity is itself deprecated in the same section of the documentation.